# Ordering a subset of columns by date r

Tags: r, columnsorting

I have a data frame which part of the columns are not in the correct order (they are dates). See:

```
data1989 <- data.frame("date_fire" = c("1987-02-01", "1987-07-03", "1988-01-01"), 
                       "Foresttype" = c("oak", "pine", "oak"),
                       "meanSolarRad" = c(500, 550, 450),
                       "meanRainfall" = c(600, 300, 450),
                       "meanTemp" = c(14, 15, 12),
                       "1988.01.01" = c(0.5, 0.589, 0.66), 
                       "1986.06.03" = c(0.56, 0.447, 0.75), 
                       "1986.10.19" = c(0.8, NA, 0.83),
                       "1988.01.19" = c(0.75, 0.65,0.75), 
                       "1986.06.19" = c(0.1, 0.55,0.811),
                       "1987.10.19" = c(0.15, 0.12, 0.780),
                       "1988.01.19" = c(0.2, 0.22,0.32), 
                       "1986.06.19" = c(0.18, 0.21,0.23),
                       "1987.10.19" = c(0.21, 0.24, 0.250),
                       check.names = FALSE,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

> data1989
   date_fire Foresttype meanSolarRad meanRainfall meanTemp 1988.01.01 1986.06.03 1986.10.19 1988.01.19 1986.06.19 1987.10.19 1988.01.19 1986.06.19 1987.10.19
1 1987-02-01        oak          500          600       14      0.500      0.560       0.80       0.75      0.100       0.15       0.20       0.18       0.21
2 1987-07-03       pine          550          300       15      0.589      0.447         NA       0.65      0.550       0.12       0.22       0.21       0.24
3 1988-01-01        oak          450          450       12      0.660      0.750       0.83       0.75      0.811       0.78       0.32       0.23       0.25
```

I would like to order the columns by increasing date, and keep the first 5 columns the same. Keep in mind that in my original dataset I have 30 initial columns to be kept the same.

Comment: Consider [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) where *date* columns are in long format with all date indicator  (previous column name) in *single* column adjacent to value column with first 5 columns repeated for each dat/value pair. Untidy data will force complex coding lacking maintainability and readability.

Comment: I should definitely check that. thanks Parfait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use dplyr here is an alternative. Note each colname would have to be unique. In you df there were some duplicate ones

```
library(dplyr)

data1989 <- data.frame("date_fire" = c("1987-02-01", "1987-07-03", "1988-01-01"), 
                       "Foresttype" = c("oak", "pine", "oak"),
                       "meanSolarRad" = c(500, 550, 450),
                       "meanRainfall" = c(600, 300, 450),
                       "meanTemp" = c(14, 15, 12),
                       "1988.01.01" = c(0.5, 0.589, 0.66), 
                       "1986.06.03" = c(0.56, 0.447, 0.75), 
                       "1986.10.19" = c(0.8, NA, 0.83),
                       "1988.01.19" = c(0.75, 0.65,0.75), 
                       "1986.06.19" = c(0.1, 0.55,0.811),
                       "1987.10.19" = c(0.15, 0.12, 0.780),
                       # "1988.01.19" = c(0.2, 0.22,0.32),
                       # "1986.06.19" = c(0.18, 0.21,0.23),
                       # "1987.10.19" = c(0.21, 0.24, 0.250),
                       check.names = FALSE,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

# Sort date column names. replace 6 with first date column 
sorted_colnames = sort(names(data1989)[6:ncol(data1989)])

# Sort columns. Replace 5 with last non-date column
data1989 %>% 
  select(1:5, sorted_colnames)
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented, try to avoid wide formatted data with columns that contain data elements such as dates, category values, other indicators. Instead use long-formatted, [***tidy***](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) data where ordering is much easier including aggregation, merging, plotting, and modeling.

Specifically, consider `reshape` to melt dates into one field such as *quarter* with *value*. Then `order` *quarter* column easily:

```
# RESHAPE WIDE TO LONG
long_data1989 <- reshape(data1989, varying = names(data1989)[6:ncol(data1989)],
                         times = names(data1989)[6:ncol(data1989)],
                         v.names = "value", timevar = "quarter", ids = NULL,
                         new.row.names = 1:1E4, direction = "long")

# ORDER DATES AND RESET row.names
long_data1989 <- `row.names<-`(with(long_data1989, long_data1989[order(date_fire, quarter),]),
                               NULL)

long_data1989
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/HEEB98431)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the column names that are dates to `Date` class, do the `order` and then use that as column index

```
i1 <- grep('^\\d{4}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}$', names(data1989))
data1989[c(seq_len(i1[1]-1), order(as.Date(names(data1989)[i1], "%Y.%m.%d")) + i1[1]-1)]
# date_fire Foresttype meanSolarRad meanRainfall meanTemp 1986.06.03 1986.06.19 1986.06.19.1 1986.10.19 1987.10.19
#1 1987-02-01        oak          500          600       14      0.560      0.100         0.18       0.80       0.15
#2 1987-07-03       pine          550          300       15      0.447      0.550         0.21         NA       0.12
#3 1988-01-01        oak          450          450       12      0.750      0.811         0.23       0.83       0.78
#  1987.10.19.1 1988.01.01 1988.01.19 1988.01.19.1
#1         0.21      0.500       0.75         0.20
#2         0.24      0.589       0.65         0.22
#3         0.25      0.660       0.75         0.32
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun! That is creating, though, some weird column names; for example the last one, adding ".1"

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo okay, if there are duplicate column names (by default the data.frame checks allow only unique column names and it will convert using `make.unique` to append `.1`, `.2` etc at the end, when you have duplicates

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo I would consider keeping it unique column names rather than duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution (similar to @Parfaits):

```
# Reshape dataframe wide --> long:

df_long <- 
  reshape(data1989,
          direction = "long",
          varying = which(!(is.na(as.Date(names(data1989), "%Y.%m.%d")))),
          idvar = which(is.na(as.Date(names(data1989), "%Y.%m.%d"))),
          v.names = "value",
          times = na.omit(as.Date(names(data1989), "%Y.%m.%d")),
          timevar = "date_surveyed",
          new.row.names = 1:(nrow(data1989)*length(na.omit(as.Date(names(data1989), 
                                                         "%Y.%m.%d")))))
# Order the data frame and reset the index: 

ordered_df_long <- data.frame(df_long[with(df_long, order(date_fire, date_surveyed)),],
                              row.names = NULL)
```